# How do I set up "Remote Debugging"of Wildfly 20 from Eclipse 2020-06

Tags: eclipse, wildfly, remote-debugging

Where can I find current instructions for how to set up Remote Debugging of Wildfly 20 from Eclipse 2020-06? My searches have found posts going back to 2014 they don't work. My most recent attempt is to follow https://tools.jboss.org/documentation/howto/configure_remote_server.html. This has no date on it and it is for connection to EAP 6.1 instead of Wildfly 20 but at least it is from tools.jboss.org and the instructions matched Eclipse 2020-06.

The problem is that when I right click on on the new Server just created with these instructions and select Debug I get the following error:

```
failed to copy to /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/MyApp.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF on host 192.168.1.19
The requested path is not found on the remote system.
```

Here are what I think are important facts:

1. The path /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments DOES exist on the Wildfly 20 server @ 192.168.1.19.
2. The Wildfly 20 server is started with /opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/standalone/deployments/MyApp.war in place. The Management console shows that MyApp is Deployed and I can access the app from a remote machine so Wildfly and the server are running.
3. I can connect from Eclipse to the Wildfly server using the Remote Systems item that creating the new Server created. In particular, I can use the root item to "roam around" the file system on the Wildfly server so that suggest to me that Eclipse can establish a connection to the Wildfly server.
4. The instructions in the URL above did not include this but in the Server's Properties the Web and Management ports were both 0. I manually set them to 8080 and 9990 respectively.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attempt to debug a remote Wildfly 20 server failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63729523/attempt-to-debug-a-remote-wildfly-20-server-failing)

Answer (score 0):

Since your installation is on /opt I guess it was done with root privileges. I'm not sure your user has sufficient rights to be able to access those paths.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell /opt is the recommended installation location but I finally got the server to at least deploy so that problem is solved. See updated question at [Attempt to debug a remote Wildfly 20 server failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63729523/attempt-to-debug-a-remote-wildfly-20-server-failing).