# Attempt to debug a remote Wildfly 20 server failing

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly, remote-debugging

I have I have configured Eclipse 2020-06 to deploy to a Wildfly 20 Service running on a remote Ubuntu 20 VM. Doing this created a Remote Debug Configuration.

When I Run that Remote Debug Configuration I instantly get the error:
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect

Here are what I think are important facts:

1. Wildfly is running as a service @ 192.168.1.19.
2. I have uncommented the JAVA_OPTS line in standalone.conf so that the service starts up in Debug on port 8787. I confirm this with:

   ps -aux | grep wildfly

   wildfly    19124  0.0  0.0  18208  2816 ?        Ss   16:41   0:00 /bin/bash /opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh standalone standalone.xml 0.0.0.0
   wildfly    19134  0.0  0.0   2612  1560 ?        S    16:41   0:00 /bin/sh /opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone.xml -b 0.0.0.0
   wildfly    19238  8.3 23.3 1724264 936448 ?      Sl   16:41   3:52 java -D[Standalone] -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true **-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8787,server=y,suspend=n** --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /opt/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/wildfly/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/wildfly -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/wildfly/standalone -c standalone.xml -b 0.0.0.0
   wizard     20383  0.0  0.0  17664   664 pts/3    S+   17:27   0:00 grep --color=auto wildfly
3. In Eclipse, the Remote Debug Configuration shows:
   Host = 192.168.1.19
   Port = 8787
4. In the Remote Systems View I can select 192.168.1.19 and sftp Files and I am able to roam the file system on the Wildfly server so I know there is connectivity between the two systems.
5. As soon as I run the Remote Debug Configuration I instantly get the error.

One question is where do I provide credentials for the Remote Debug Configuration? I would expect that that is needed to allow connection.

Wildfly is running in debug mode on 8787 and the Remote Debug Configuration uses 8787 so what is going wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are incoming connections on that port allowed on that VM?

Comment: I assume by "that VM" you mean the Wildfly VM. ss | grep 8787 shows tcp   ESTAB  0      0                                   192.168.1.19:8787                                192.168.1.16:50610 so I interpet that as meaning the port is open. Is there a better way to confirm this? Thanks.